# Animate background color of table rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-animate

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/yR6jc/144/).

Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("Table-1");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;



for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {


row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.name = "animate";
cell1.id = i ;
var content = document.createElement("output");                
content.innerHTML = i ;
cell1.appendChild(content);
rowCount++;

  // if (i%2 == 0) {
       setInterval(function() {
           $(input[name="animate"]).animate( { backgroundColor: '#f08080' }, 'slow')
           .animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 'slow'); 
                 }, 1000);
   // }

}​
```

HTML:

```
<table id="Table-1" border="1">

                    <tr>
                        <th><center>List</center></th>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

​

I built my table with javascript and I wanted to animate a few rows every one second but it does not works for all rows.However, when I animate a particular row it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution (to my code) is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/yR6jc/152/)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your script:

- You create `output` element instead of `input`
- You name the `td`, but later you reference `input` in the selector
- You are missing apostrophes in the selector
- You start multiple animations in the loop for no reason
- You mix vanilla javascript with jquery (this is just cosmetics)

Change the selector to:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('table td input').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#f08080'
    }, 'slow').animate({
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }, 'slow');
}, 1000);
```

See updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yR6jc/149/).

Answer (score 1):

Same HTML, better formed:

```
<table id="Table-1" border="1">                   
    <tr>
        <th><center>List</center></th>
    </tr>
</table> ​
```

Working JavaScript:

```
var table = document.getElementById("Table-1");

for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {   
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.className = 'animate';
    cell.id = i;
    cell.innerHTML = i;
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row);     

    setInterval(function() {
       $('td.animate').animate( { backgroundColor: '#f08080' }, 'slow')
       .animate( { backgroundColor: 'red' }, 'slow');
    }, 1000);
}​
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/yR6jc/151/

Comment: Just as an alternative, you might want to use `insertRow` and `insertCell` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.insertRow . Obviously your solution works, but when working with tables, it's nice to use these methods :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using CSS3 Animations, no jQuery needed.

Its simply, define the animation:

```
@keyframes back-animation
{
from {background: white;}
to {background: red;}
}
```

And apply it to the element, in your case just the  or classes in the columns you want

```
#Table-1{
   width:200px;
   text-align:center;
   background:red;
   animation:back-animation 2s linear 1s infinite alternate;
}
```

Here is the JS Fiddle with the required prefixes.

http://jsfiddle.net/yR6jc/156/

ps: this doesn't work on Internet Explorer.